# Angular Testing - Trouble mocking Service with $http dependency

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a controller with a custom service dependency.  The service has a dependency on $http.  In my controller, I'm making reference to the "then" part of the promise, but that is making the test code blow up.  How are you supposed to mock a service and test a controller dependent on it?  [Here's a plunker with the whole debacle.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ffiOB73gMawDqJ0a4tis?p=preview)  My service looks like this:

```
  app.service('FooService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
      getFoo: function(){
        return $http.get('Foo');
      },
      getBar: function(){
        return 'bar';
      }
    };
  }]);
```

The controller:

```
  app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', 'FooService', function(scope, FooService){
    scope.hi = function() {};

    scope.getFoo = function(){
      FooService.getFoo().then(function(data){
        scope.bar = data.data;
      });
    };

    scope.getBar = function(){
      scope.bar = FooService.getBar();
    };
  }]);
```

In my understanding, the $http dependency should not be on the controller in order to drive testability and separation of concerns.  However, now I'm having trouble with the promise...  How should this be done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $httpBackend to mock out the http call. In your plunker the main reason httpBackend wasn't working is because you were calling `respond(1)` which responded with an HTTP status code of 1. If you change it to `respond(200, 1)` then it should work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ubJH3iABaGpINFKTvGTx?p=preview

You can also just mock out the FooService using angular's [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) service to create a promise similar to the one $http returns. You'll also need to call `scope.$apply()` to let the promise resolve similar to how you call `$httpBackend.flush()` in the other example. Here is a working sample:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3xbCmBTQ4ChVlhaTZXwC?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!  IMO testing in Angular isn't as easy as advertised - lots of ways to screw things up.